pyserial not detecting serial ports created with Virtual Serial Ports Emulator, even though I can connect with PuTTY, and is listed in "mode" command
I run this script after setting up a port with the Virtual Serial Ports Emulator (VSPE), and even when running as admin, no ports are found.
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = sorted([port.device for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()])
if ports:
    for port in ports:
        print(port)
else:
    print('no ports found')

Same thing with the following script using win32com.client:
import win32com.client

def list_serial_ports():
    # Create a WMI object
    wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")
    # Query for serial ports
    ports = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort")
    
    # Print the names of the serial ports
    for port in ports:
        print(port.DeviceID)

list_serial_ports()

I tried reinstalling pyserial, which didn't help. I run the mode command, and the port I created is shown in the listed ports. I can connect to the port with PuTTY. The ports are not listed in the Device Manager.

Since you mentioned win32com i assume you are using windows. I'm not very very familiar with serial ports on windows but i would guess its some sort of access rights problem. For linux you need to be in the 'dialout' group to have access to the serial ports without using root. I would guess there is a similar thing on windows.
